# My MATCH query doesnt return all matched documents Elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, match

I have 350 documents in my Elastic index, they all have feed_id 15621. I can go to each and every one of them directly by index and can see they are all there and have the right feed_id.

But when I do this request (below) I only find 221 documents. The others arent found. This is a problem that started yesterday after working fine for months (At least I think it worked fine).

How do I get my search to show all 350 products?

```
GET products-nl/_search
{
  "size": 3000, 
  "_source": "eancode", 
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "products.feed_id": 15621
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: added request

Comment: There is not a *request below* or am I missing something?

Comment: You are right, I added it!

Comment: Hi, would you run a `term` aggregation on `products.feed_id` to check how many docs are found for id 15621?

Comment: @glenacota Hi! I ran the aggs and it also finds 221 docs :(

Comment: What about the docs that are not matched? Do they have something in common? (maybe a wrong mapping?)

Comment: Ooooeh, that's interesting, could it be that it won't get indexed because the document misses one of the mappings?

Comment: Not sure, what does your mapping look like? Notably, the mapping of the `feed_id` field

Comment: @glenacota ! Your comment gave me an idea! Products is an array of products. He only finds the documents where feed_id = 15621 in the first item! Should I have indexed this differently or search for something like products[].feed_id??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190033/discussion-between-glenacota-and-hans-wassink).